# $animate callback promise not work in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-animation

Reference to $animate [api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate), $animation supported callback promise since angular1.3.

But my code not worked

```
angular.module('app', [ngAnimate])
.factory('test', ['$animate', '$q', function($animate, $q) {
  return {
    test: function(element) {
      $animate.enter(angular.element("#node"), element)
      .then(function() {
        console.log('entered');
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

It returned

```
Error: $animate.enter(...).then is not a function
```

Both of my angular and angular-animate are 1.3.0-beta.19
Please help!

---

**edit**
Problem solved by myself.

Because callback promises supported since v1.3.0-rc.0, but not v1.3.0-beta.19

Comment: Fix the syntax first, `return { function(element) { ...` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by myself.

Because callback promises supported since v1.3.0-rc.0, but not v1.3.0-beta.19

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change:

```
$animate.enter(angular.element("#node"), element)
```

to

```
$animate.enter(element.find("#node"), element)
```

Comment: I don't think selecting #node is correct in this situation. $animate.enter is expecting an element object to insert as it's first argument. Try $animate.enter(angular.element("<div>Hello</div>"), element)

Comment: Both `angular.element("#node")` and `element.find("#node")` did append `#node` to the `element`. Problem is it said `.then is not a function`.